# Cache in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am working in a project where I have to show the menu based on user_type login. I have kept user, user_type and menu in DB. Now when user login, I have to show the list of menus to show this user.

When user login, I can create the Cache and store username, type and menus in cache. But how to show these menus in view and iterate the same.

Thanks,
Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a List, then you can try to fetch the data like below code, as specified in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaCache):

```
Cache.getAs[User]("item.key")
```

And to iterate through the List in View, you can do something like this:

```
@for(menu <- Cache.getAs[List[Menu]]("menu-list")){
     <li>@menu.name</li>
}
```

Note: Remember that cache values will be available for other users, so if some user will perform similar action in the almost the same time it will get value from others action. It would be better to make sure that the cache keys contains some user specific, unique elements, like:

```
Cache.set("Menu"+currentUser.id, Menu, 60)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Working for me. Some times the menu object get null, why ? Even I have added time to expire is 60 minutes. Please suggest so that I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Do you set it to 3600, right ? Because the third parameter is in seconds.. The other work around is to remove the timeout part and remove it using `Cache.remove("item.key")`. If that still doesn't work, I think that's another problem, so better put a new question..

Comment: You are right, did the same but still getting the same issue. Can I store the menu objects in session in play.

Comment: Yes, you can.. Back than I considered to ask you about using session instead of cache.. But, since you're dealing with menu access permission, so for security sake it won't be a good way to save menu objects in session.. Because the value can be changed manually by the client..

Comment: Thats the reason I was thinking about Caching. But caching is giving null values then I wont be able to get the list of menus. Can we do one thing, check the menu object and if it is null restore it ?

Comment: Yup, I think you are right, you can try to get the value and check if it's null you can re-assign your cache.. But, how can you get the username if it's already removed from the cache ?

Comment: Will keep the username in session and will keep menu object in cache. But I do not know how to call controllers method from view.

Comment: My logic did work here. Added userId in session and menus in cache. To access the menus userId is the key. Also added code in interceptor to update the cache if it is NULL. So now we are not getting null values. Hope this will be useful for others too.